# swift show array of error messages in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I wonder if its possible to show error messages in a UIAlertController.

My server sends error messages back as JSON.

I can get each error message using:

```
if let errorVal = errorVal {

    if let items = errorVal["errors"].array {
        for item in items {
            print(item)
        }
    }


}
```

Now I wonder how I can show the errors in a AlertController.
The AlertController's message parameter expect a string but my errors come as JSON then cast to .array

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey! :)", message: "My Errors", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could build up a string with description of each error  ( or just message ) and show that ( may be too much to show ). It would go like this:

```
var errorMessages = ""
if let errorVal = errorVal {
    if let items = errorVal["errors"].array {
        for item in items {
            print(item)
            errorMessages = errorMessages + item + "\n" // if this is NSError you can use description, message or code
        }
    }
}
```

and later on you can do something like:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey! :)", message: errorMessages , preferredStyle: .Alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```